# How to overlay a face in Emacs that ONLY modifies the underline

Tags: emacs

In my color theme settings, I have this:

```
`(flyspell-incorrect ((t (:underline "#ff7bbb"))))
```

When I am editing an org-mode file with something like:

```
* Expedia
```

The face is the usual org level 1 face while I am typing "* Expedi" until I type the last "a" of Expedia, at which time the word is underlined by flyspell-incorrect AND the foreground is changed to red.  How can I tell it not to change the color to red, but to only modify the underline and inherit the foreground from what the face would otherwise be (e.g. org level 1, 2, etc).

Comment: Perhaps modifying `flyspell-highlight-incorrect-region` with a provision for `(if (eq major-mode 'org-mode) . . .` would be the best approach . . .  There is also a `flyspell-incorrect-hook` that *perhaps* could be used -- i.e., *List of functions to be called when incorrect words are encountered*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flyspell-incorrect` inherits from the basic `error` face, whose default specification is a red foreground.

As custom themes do not clear the attributes from the face' default specification, your `flyspell-incorrect` face still inherits from `error` and thus has a red foreground.

To remove the foreground, “unlink” `flycheck-incorrect` from `error` by unsetting the `:inherit` attribute in your specification, e.g.

```
`(flyspell-incorrect ((t (:underline "#ff7bbb" :inherit unspecified))))
```