# How to disable color in flyspell (emacs)?

Tags: emacs, colors, flyspell

I would like to prevent flyspell from changing the foreground color of words, and just add a red underline.

I've tried the suggestions here, but it doesn't have any effect: [How to overlay a face in Emacs that ONLY modifies the underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472470/how-to-overlay-a-face-in-emacs-that-only-modifies-the-underline). Perhaps I'm missunderstanding the answer, but setting `inherit: undefined` in the customize interface does nothing.

Guessing I should customize `flyspell-duplicate` and `flyspell-incorrect`, but how?

Comment: the default `face-attribute` for `flyspell-incorrect` is just underline. Perhaps you have modified the value of the `face-attribute` in your .emacs?

Anyways, you might want to check on how to use `set-face-attribute` on `flyspell-incorrect`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @chakravarthy-raghunandan the issue was with a local customization.

Turns out the theme I'm using set this, so my customizations were overwritten.

Putting this in my `init.el` fixed the issue:

```
(custom-theme-set-faces
 'cyberpunk
 '(flyspell-duplicate ((t (:weight bold :underline (:color "#ff0000" :style wave)))))
 '(flyspell-incorrect ((t (:weight bold :underline (:color "#ff0000" :style wave))))))
```

Comment: This snipped helped me change the appearance of flyspell!